# How do I uninstall cmder?

Tags: cmder

I can't uninstall `cmder`.
I have tried to open `cmder` and run the following command:

```
cmder.exe /UNREGISTER ALL
```

Run Regedit.

- Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell and delete the cmder folder.
- Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell and delete the cmder folder.

The problem is that there are no cmder folders in either of those registry locations and cmder is still installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is cmder installed? For me, for instance, cmder is simply an executable in a folder. Removing the executable, 'uninstalls' the application for me. You could also try uninstalling with the windows app manager in Windows Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rickjerrity is correct.

By removing the directory containing Cmder, you will uninstall it, no need to touch the registry.  If you don't remember where that directory is, you can execute a Get-ChildItem command via `gci -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue Cmder.exe` from the `c:\` directory and it will recursively search the C drive (note, if you have other drives you will need to do it for that as well).

If you want to install and uninstall Cmder programmatically, I suggest using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) (a package manager for Windows).  The Cmder package is at this [link](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cmder).

This will allow you do the following in scripting or on the command line:

- to install the package using the `choco install cmder` command;
- and to uninstall using the `choco uninstall cmder` command;
- and check if it's already installed using the `choco list --local-only` command.